# add rule to firewalld in Centos7 to allow all traffic from a server

Tags: firewall, iptables, rhel, centos7

I have a small cluster with Centos7. I'm trying how to use the new firewalld.

I need a rule to allow all traffic between those servers.
I was able to do it with:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s [hostname] -j ACCEPT
```

and it worked. But now I have to use firewall-cmd because of Centos 7. How can I  add a rule to allow all traffic between my nodes?
I'm trying to run MPI on them but the firewalld is rejecting the connection so the solution I thought of came to this.

My current firewall-cmd configuration is:

```
$ firewall-cmd --list-all
work (default, active)
  interfaces: eno1
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ipp-client ssh
  ports:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to add source using this:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=work --add-source=[host_IP]
```

But still couldn't make the MPI application run correctly.
Then decided that the only way to enable MPI on this cluster is to make a rule to accept all traffic between the nodes. 
I ran those 2 commands.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -s  [server+IP] -j ACCEPT

firewall-cmd --reload
```

and it worked like  a charm.Not sure if this is the best solution security wise though.

Comment: It is not a bad solution. What I'm using nowdays is something similar. `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" port port=10051 protocol=tcp source address="193.XX.XX.XXX" accept' --permanent` With this the connection on 10051 is allowed even if the interface is in the group `drop`. This way everything would be dropped, noone can come in UNLESS the source IP is the one I've specified AND the PORT. Easy :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly check which zone your firewall is using ATM:

```
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
```

Then try the following:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
```

Don't forget to replace the zone and the port with the one you are looking for. After that you need to reload the firewall:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

This should solve your issue. For further commands use the --help or Google.

Comment: thanks, my problem with MPI was not solved by adding ports (usually ssh or 22). It was solved by adding the whole server IP to the sources as explained in my answer.